# How do I modify the code for the Cinnamon Applet on-screen-keyboard@cinnamon.org

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, on-screen-keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I am working on my first Linux project as an aspiring developer and would like help accessing the code for the on-screen-keyboard in Cinnamon 5.6.5. I can find the file, but I lack the experience necessary to understand how to open it for modification. How do I look at the on-screen-keyboard file and access it for modification on my own personal machine?

Comment: Welcome to [Super User](https://superuser.com/ "https://superuser.com/").  Your question doesn't include enough detail. Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask "https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask") then edit your question to include the details of your research, what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.  For example  [Hacking the Virtual Keyboard w/ an Original Scientific Alphabet](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2314759#p2314759 "https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2314759#p2314759")

Comment: If you are an aspiring dev, start by writing your own code. Modifying existing stuff is often much harder (and you learn less).

Comment: Frankly, I can hardly tolerate the way you people read and write English, let alone code. How many coders that you know of practice Unit Testing as a one to one discipline? finding a coder that cares is a $15,000,000 endeavor at a minimum. Hell, I've got more dismemberment victims in my family than I've found willing tutelage about anything through a Stack Exchange. If you want to brag, tell me how to look at the code for the on-screen-keyboard@cinnamon.org anywhere, whether in the applet docs on the Cinnamon Github page (which has no coherent TLD a beginner could find) or w/ the Mint terminal